# Selenium python recursive text scrape

Tags: python, selenium

Here is a small piece of html from this link [here](http://www.saksfifthavenue.com/main/ProductDetail.jsp?FOLDER%3C%3Efolder_id=2534374306622397&PRODUCT%3C%3Eprd_id=845524446698001&R=887712886777&P_name=Tory+Burch&N=306622397+1553&bmUID=l3aks7hi)

```
<div class="price-view">
  <div class="price component component-3 clearfix list-and-sale-price">
    <div class="list-price float-left mR20px striken">
      <label>Was</label>
      <div class="value">$250.00</div>
    </div>
    <div class="sale-price float-left">
      <label>Now</label>
      <div class="value">$150.00</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to pull the price $150 in this instance, but I would like the same code to print $575 in [this](http://www.saksfifthavenue.com/main/ProductDetail.jsp?FOLDER%3C%3Efolder_id=2534374306624277&PRODUCT%3C%3Eprd_id=845524446867296&R=887804098231&P_name=Alberto+Fermani&N=306624277&bmUID=l3zHLM9) link

```
<div class="price-view">
  <div class="price component component-3 clearfix">
    <div class="list-price float-left mR20px ">
      <div class="value">$575.00</div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

For obvious reasons the xpath code below will not work in more than one instance.

```
price = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="saksBody"]/div[4]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[6]/div/div/div/div').text
```

So, I have tried looking into code like this:

```
price = driver.find_element_by_class_name('value')
```

But, this is not specific enough.

Is there some way to print all the text in the `<div class="price-view">`? Then I could use regex to solve the rest.

This code does not seem to grab the text inside tags in the tag

```
price = driver.find_element_by_class_name('price-view').text
```

To be very specific, I would like to know how to output:

```
Was$250.00Now$150.00
```

and

```
$575.00
```

For the first and second links respectively.

Answer (score 0):

In both cases, the pricing is in a `DIV` with class `price-view` so we use the CSS selector `div.price-view` to grab the outer element. It then looks to see if the `list-and-sale-price` class exists. If it does, then we have both a list and sale price so grab the sale price. Either way the list price exists so we grab it. This way you don't have to regex the pieces.

```
priceView = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.price-view")
if (priceView.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.list-and-sale-price"))
    # there is a list and sale price, grab the sale price
    salePrice = priceView.find_element_by_css_selector("div.sale-price > div.value")).text
# in either case, grab the list price
listPrice = priceView.find_element_by_css_selector("div.list-price > div.value")).text
```